# How do i speed up this piece of code?

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I have a function, that takes a list as an argument:

```
def f(x):
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        if j == '0':
            x[i] = '1'
        else:
            x[i] = '0'
    return ''.join(x)
```

This function is used like this:

```
while len(x) <= n:
    x = ''.join([x,f([i for i in x])])
```

This code halts if n > 10000000. How could it be improved? 
Here is what cProfile says:

```
         98 function calls in 3.974 seconds

   Ordered by: call count

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
       48    0.235    0.005    0.235    0.005 {method 'join' of 'str' objects}
   25    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
   24    3.740    0.156    3.965    0.165 1:9(f)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
```

Comment: Working code belongs to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: How is Code Review not one of the flag options? I would think that would be one of the most common sites questions would be moved to.

Comment: @carcigenicate - because it is rare that person active on both sites would see such question and only recommend migration when appropriate. Feel free to discuss on meta.

Comment: Your function is called `f`, but there are no `f`s in your 2nd code snippet. Additionally, you don't define `st` in `f`.

Comment: There is also no mention of `n` inside the loop and no sign of the `x` gets shorter.

Comment: Sorry for confusion with function names, it came from different test versions

Comment: @AlexHall n is just an integer and x should be getting longer

Comment: It looks like you were generating this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence Were you aware? You can probably find ways to develop a faster algorithm there rather than just optimising the implementation in terms of Python details.

Comment: [This does not belong on Code Review!](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) This question has a specific goal (improve performance) and only performance. Also note. While it is not required that code already works as intended on SO, this does not imply that working code does not belong on SO. Closing as *unclear* is misleading - seems perfectly clear to me what Sharky is asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version:

```
def f(x):
    for i,j in enumerate(x):
        if j == '0':
            x[i] = '1'
        else:
            x[i] = '0'
    return ''.join(x)

​
def assemble(x, n):
    while len(x) <= n:
        x = ''.join([x,f([i for i in x])])
    return x
```

Faster version 1:

```
def assemble_fast1(x, n):
    res = list(x)
    while len(res) <= n:
        res.extend(['01'[c=='0'] for c in res])
    return ''.join(res)
```

Faster version 2:

```
def assemble_fast2(x, n):
    res = list(x)
    while len(res) <= n:
        res.extend(['1' if c == '0' else '0' for c in res])
    return ''.join(res)
```

Some timings:

```
In [293]:
n = int(1e7)
x = '101011'
assemble_fast1(x, n) == assemble_fast2(x, n) == assemble(x, n)
Out[293]:
True

In [294]:
%timeit assemble_fast1(x, n)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.85 s per loop

In [295]:
%timeit assemble_fast2(x, n)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.67 s per loop

In [296]:
%timeit assemble(x, n)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.15 s per loop
```

So `assemble_fast2` is about twice as fast as your version.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your goal correctly, here are some approaches you could try. I'll let you do the timing.

```
>>> print x
11001011
>>> print ''.join('1' if c == '0' else '0' for c in x)
00110100
>>> print ''.join(str(int(c == '0')) for c in x)
00110100
>>> print ''.join(map(str, map(int, map('0'.__eq__, x))))
00110100
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> print ''.join(map(str, imap(int, imap('0'.__eq__, x))))
00110100
>>> y = bin(int(x, 2) ^ ((1 << len(x)) - 1))[2:]
>>> print y
110100
>>> print '0' * (len(x) - len(y)) + y
00110100
```

The last one will only work if you're strictly working with 1s and 0s. Actually it would probably be better to use `~` but I need to go to bed now. Google "python flip bits".

Comment: How about the classic `print ''.join('01'[c=='0'] for c in x)`?

Comment: @pzp oooh, that's good. And in map form that's `''.join(map('01'.__getitem__, map('0'.__eq__, x)))`

Comment: I've already tried map and it was even slower. It seems to me that all the mess is in iterating over continuously increasing string with for loop. Could it be replaced or maybe this code could be modified somehow?

Comment: @Sharky Well you have an O(n^2) algorithm for a very large n so what you really need is to tell us what the bigger problem you're trying to solve is so that a completely different approach can be taken.

Comment: @Sharky Why don't you convert your list to `bool` and `not` it? It's really fast in numpy.